# SQL Query pauses

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

My query seems to be stalling every so many passes through the query.

```
        status_text.Text = "Check existing records...";
        status_text.Refresh();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(df_text_filename))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(df_text_filename + "_temp"))
            {
                while ((product = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (product != _aff_svc.DFHeaderProd)
                    {
                        df_product = _product_factory.GetProductData(_vsi, product);
                    }
                    status_text.Text = "Checking for existing record of vendor record ID " + df_product.SKU;
                    status_text.Refresh();
                    if (_pctlr.GetBySKU(df_product.SKU) != null)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    writer.WriteLine(product);
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
                writer.Close();
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        System.IO.File.Delete(df_text_filename);
        System.IO.File.Move(df_text_filename + "_temp", df_text_filename);
```

The code quickly runs through the GetBySKU about 10 times, pauses for about a second or so, then quickly does another ten records. This occurs throughout my processes, not just with this particular query.

It also occurs whether or not I have the Application.DoEvents() fire.

The other problem is that it is not consistent.  I can be working like this for a few hours, then all of a sudden, it will zip through the loop as intended (expected).

My SQL server is running on the same machine as the program.

I looked into dedicating resources to the server to mitigate this behavior, but have found nothing.

Comment: Have you tried using [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx)?  It may give you a clue as to whether the issue is on the application or database side.

Comment: I notice that in the "product was not null" case, it uses `continue` without updating the UI (it skips `DoEvents`) - is there a chance that a "stall" here is actually just a block of things that are already done? What profiling have you done to place the blame at the SQL? Are you logging the SQL times? If not: do that first. I assume the "SQL query" here is the `GetBySKU` - any chance we can see that?

Comment: Also, every time you use `Application.DoEvents`, your CPU kills a kitten - just sayin'.

Comment: @marcgravell isn't GC.Collect() responsible for killing kittens?

Comment: @Uwe `GC.Collect` is responsible for puppies

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you're program is parsing a text file for product info and then as it parses, in a while **loop** you're executing a couple SQL queries.  It's almost always a bad idea to make SQL round trips inside a loop.

Instead, I would look into parsing the file, gathering all the product ideas, closing the file and then make one call to sql passing a/many [TVPs (table valued parameters)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) to a sproc and return all the data you need from that sproc - possibly as many tables.

EDIT:
You mentioned in the comments that the file is very large with lots of processing.  You could consider batching the SQL work in lets say something like 100?

Also, if you're SQL isn't tuned it would continually slow down as more data is written.  There's not enough info in the question to analyze the indexes, query plans etc... but have a look at that as the data set grows.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data file is too hefty for me to do that on my current system.  The GetProductData is not a SQL query, it just builds the object from the text data to compare with the db.

Comment: The reason I am even doing this is because power likes to go out frequently where I am.  This process can take several hours, and I want to check to see what has already been processed before restarting.

Answer (score 0):

I will work on a batch solution later, however, this works much faster than the previous code. No pauses at all.

```
            List<Product> _prod_list = new List<Product>();
            _prod_list = ProductDataFactory.GetProductListByVendor(vendor_name);
            if (_prod_list.Count() > 0)
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(df_text_filename))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(df_text_filename + "_temp"))
                    {
                        while ((product = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            if (product != _aff_svc.DFHeaderProd)
                            {
                                df_product = _product_factory.GetProductData(_vsi, product);
                            }
                            if (_prod_list.Find(o => o.SKU == df_product.SKU) != null)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                            writer.WriteLine(product);
                        }
                        writer.Close();
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                System.IO.File.Delete(df_text_filename);
                System.IO.File.Move(df_text_filename + "_temp", df_text_filename);
            }
```

Just pulling a list of product objects and query it for existing records if there are any; if not, it skips the whole process of course.  No need to hit the db in the loop either.

Thanks.

Comment: Heh, I just ran a test on my biggest list 2.6GB source file.  Usually took all day to do this part.  It finished in less than 30 minutes!